# FourSquare Axios Request - ReactJs - Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api, axios

please help :)

I'm doing simple Axios get request, in a "Component Did Mount". In a simple/basic react app. I'm trying to get FourSquare place data for London.

My function works, as I can console.log data. Here's my component did mount code:

```
// FOURSQUARE COMPONENT DID MOUNT
componentDidMount() {
  console.log('COMPONENT DID MOUNT');
  axios.get('https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/explore…')

  .then(res => {
   console.log('data', res.data.response.groups[0].items);
// console.log('data',res.data.response.groups[0].items[0].venue.name);
   this.setState(
   { places: res.data.response.groups[0].items}
  );
 });
}
```

Please here the screenshot attached of console.log.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/ridJC.png

However, I'm trying to map through the data, to get "venue.name" in the object array/res.data.  But I keep getting the following error:

**Cannot read property 'map' of undefined**

Here is how I'm trying to map through the data....

```
const Loaders = ({places}) => {

  return (

    <section>
      <div className="columns is-multiline">
        {places.map((place, i) => <div className="column is-one-quarter" key={i}>
          <ul>
            <li>
              <div className="card-image">
                <figure className="image">
                 <h2 className="has-text-centered has-text-grey">title: {place.venue.name}</h2>
                </figure>
              </div>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>)}
      </div>
    </section>
  );
};

export default Loaders;
```

Comment: your "places" variable is invalid (not an array)... Can you check if the variable getting the correct data? Ex: dumping the places.length to the view..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason that happens because it the request is asynchronous and after the response is obtained then the places state is set. So initially, `places` is undefined. 
You can render a loading indicator in the loading state

const Loaders = ({places}) => {
  if(!places){
     return  Loading... 
  }

return (

```
<section>
  <div className="columns is-multiline">
    {places.map((place, i) => <div className="column is-one-quarter" key={i}>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <div className="card-image">
            <figure className="image">
             <h2 className="has-text-centered has-text-grey">title: {place.venue.name}</h2>
            </figure>
          </div>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>)}
  </div>
</section>
```

);
};

or initialize places to empty array in the constructor

```
constructor(props) {
   this.state = {
     places = []
   }
}
```

Comment: wait I got:
{place.venue.categories[0].name}

Comment: The reponse is deeply nested. You will need to process it to suit your UI needs. Do you know if it is always one category or there can be more categories ? Do you plan to show that in your UI ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `this.state.places` is undefined at some point. The problem could be the initial state not being set to an empty array at the start or something in the logic changing the value of `places`. Try to

```
class Foo extends React.Component {
    state = {
        places: []
    }

    render() {
        return <Loaders places={this.state.places} />>
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use the `join` function to get all the values together with a 'glue'. Something like `place.venue.formattedAddress.join(', ')`

Comment: Sorry, but in this example, how would I get through an array in this data.  For example, I'd like to get to categories.name, which you can see in this link, but I dont get anything returned..  Probably because I need to loop through it in my JSX again..

https://i.imgur.com/kzKaiJ6.png

Comment: Yeah, `categories` is an array, so you could still use `join` in cases you have more than one element in categories. `place.venue.categories.map(_ => _.name).join(', ')`